# Prevent timed function from running on local machine but not in cloud?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm using the precompiled functions technique. I made a timer function that executes once a day at around midnight. Everything works great. However now I've moved on to developing other new functions and the timer function still executes locally (which makes sense). The problem is that I don't want it to execute locally anymore (I have some API call limits with another service that I want to minimize usage of).

Is there a good way to do this? I could add some code to just return, but then if I forget to delete it and check things in, then the code won't run on the server either (it's set to build and deploy on check in). In fact, I accidentally did this last night. Similarly I could modify the function.json file to alter the time but again, I could accidentally check that in. Is there any way to detect that I'm running locally and not in Azure? If I could tell that I'm not running in the cloud then I could just do a check for that and return and not have to worry about a temporary hack that might get checked in by accident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about a good way of doing so, but I think you can use appsettings.josn which can be used at your local machine for debugging, also you can create a similar setting using app settings.

appsettings.json is only to be used at local debugging, even if it is checked in, it would not affect the server.

If you find a better solution then please update here.

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer, although I wound up using a different method that I found while implementing your idea. I realized I could make a #define in my debug configuration (that I called _LOCAL_). When I check in my code, it gets built and deployed to my Azure Functions: the build config it uses is release so the debug #defines I have aren't set there. Seems to work as well since I only run in debug locally.